# How to properly use transient keyword when de-serializing?

Tags: java, design-patterns, serializable, transient

I have the following class

```
public class Num implements Serializable, Observable {
    private int num; // number which should be serialized

    // listeners who are watching for changes in this Num
    // No need to serialize these -- pointless to do so.
    private transient Set<Observer> listeners = new HashSet<>();

    @Override public void addListener(Observer o) { listeners.add(o); }

    @Override public void removeListener(Observer o) { listeners.remove(o); }

    public void set(int newVal) {
        if (num != newVal) {
            num = newVal; // set the value.
            for (Observer o : listeners)
                o.notify(); // Notify listeners that the value changed.
        }
    }
}
```

When I serialize this class, it works well and `num` is saved. When I de-serialize the class, `num` is loaded but `listeners` **is not and is set to** `null`. My program then crashes on the line `for (Observer o : listeners)`.

I came up with some solutions but they are all terrible solutions.

**1)** Have a setup method which 'reconstructs' the `transient` fields.

```
public void setup() {
    if (listeners != null) throw new Exception("Already setup!");
    listeners = new HashSet<>();
}
```

This way is annoying through because the de-serialization method needs to remember to setup the object. It's very unintuitive for other people working on the project.

**2)** Have the `set` method automatically check and repair itself

```
public void set(int newVal) {
    if (num != newVal) {
        if (listeners == null) listeners = new HashSet<>();
        ...
    }
}
```

This way is also bad because the check will keep happening over and over, even though it only needed to be done once.

**3)** Remove `Observable` from `class Num`, get rid of `listeners`, etc. Then make a non-serializable class which contains a `Num` instance.

```
public class Num implements Serializable {
    public int num;
}

public class ObservableNum impements Observable {
    private Num n;

    public ObservableNum() { n = new Num(); } // constructor
    private ObservableNum(Num n) { this.n = n; } // constructor

    ...

    public static ObservableNum loadNum(...) {

        ObjectInputStream ois = ...;
        return new ObservableNum((Num) ois.readObject());
    }
}
```

But this way also seems needlessly complicated. Surely there must be a better solution? How is transient properly used?

Comment: For method 2, *This way is also bad because the check....* - this is a very quick op

Comment: @ScaryWombat Yes but if you think about the lifetime of these objects, the `set` function may be called hundreds of thousands of times across many objects. There is likely a much better way to approach the problem than that.

Comment: What do they say about premature optimization?  In my code I am sure I have way bigger problems to think about.

Comment: @ScaryWombat I understand your position but I'd argue this is less about premature optimization and more about CPU cycle-concious coding practices.

Comment: No need to argue ;-)  Maybe someone else will chime in.

Comment: What mechanism are you using to perform serialization? Note that Effective Java has warned for more than a decade, "__There is no reason to use Java serialization in any new system you write.__" (emphasis by Josh Bloch)

Comment: @jaco0646 I develop a desktop program used by a few hundred users. The program currently uses a very primitive way of saving preferences to the hard drive (creating a file output stream and outputting the preferences in a comma separated large string). There are not enough preferences to warrant a database. Can you provide an alternative and/or elaborate more on the java serialization quote you referenced?

Comment: [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) is very popular for serializing Java objects to JSON or XML. I would highly recommend picking up Effective Java if you want to learn more about `Serializable`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [documentation](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/javaserial.html):

> There is, however, a strange yet crafty solution. By using a built-in
>   feature of the serialization mechanism, developers can enhance the
>   normal process by providing two methods inside their class files.

Those methods are:

1. `private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream out) throws IOException;`
2. `private void readObject(ObjectInputStream in) throws IOException,
   ClassNotFoundException;`

So, you just need to implement `readObject` which looks like below and after default deserialisation just create new instance of `HashSet`. Example:

```
private void readObject(ObjectInputStream in) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    in.defaultReadObject();
    this.listeners = new HashSet<>();
}
```

Comment: Brilliant. This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Method 2 is a good approach. In my practice I will always check for null when using for loop or stream / foreach with collection.

An optimization can be done by initializing the set in addListener method so you can directly return in set method if the collection is empty.

For your performance concerning, a null-check statement will not affect the performance as the for-loop and notify method will cost more time and it can be ignored.

Comment: I see what you're saying now. You're saying, just leave the collection `null` until a caller actually wants to add something. Only then will you initialize it and add. I believe in this situation that's what I'll do. But what about situations where I have say... three variables which are very important to the object's function? Saving them all would be a waste. But making the `transient` would lead to half of the object being `null`.